# Splitting text and putting it into dictionary

Tags: c#

I have text with 600 words and I'm supposed to delete every quotation marks, numbers(years, dates, ..), digits ,... I should only have words, and I have to put in into dictionary.

So I have tried to go through with for each loop and get the first letter and save it in a list. Then I split every row in a word.
e.g.:

```
You are pretty.
```

```
You
are
pretty
```

The problem there are words in a row they're still same but they shouldn't be same. I've tried to fix it but I couldn't find any solution.

```
 public Dictionary<string, int> words = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        public Dictionary<char, List<string>> firstletter = new Dictionary<char, List<string>>();
        public Aufgabe(string filename)
        {
            string filler = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜ";
            foreach (char f in filler)
            {
                firstletter[f] = new List<string>();
            }

            Load(filename);

        }
        public void Load(string filename)
        {
            List<string> w = new List<string>();
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filename);



            while (!r.EndOfStream)
            {
                string row = r.ReadLine();
                string[] parts = row.Split(' ');
                string[] sonderzeichen = new string[] { "@", ",", ".", ";", "'", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "(", ")", "{",
                    "}", "!", "?", "/", "\"", "&", "+", "-", "–" };
                string[] list = new string[parts.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    string a = parts[i];
                    foreach (string s in sonderzeichen)
                    {
                        if (s != "-")
                        {
                            a = a.Replace(s, string.Empty);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (a.Length == 1)
                            {
                                a = string.Empty;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    list[i] = a;
                }
                parts = list;

                foreach (string a in parts)
                {
                    if (words.ContainsKey(a))
                    {
                        words[a] += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        words.Add(a, 1);
                    }

                    string b = a.ToUpper();
                    if (b == "")
                        continue;
                    List<string> letter = firstletter[b[0]];
                    if (!letter.Contains(a))
                    {
                        letter.Add(a);
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Zen observations such as "they're still same but they shouldn't be same" do not help the people trying to provide an answer. :-/

Comment: Yea sryy e.g. state-of-the-art it should be state of the art but it didn't change

Comment: Why not just use a regex like `Regex.Split(sentence, @"\W+");`?

Comment: @ggorlen Didn't know about that I will try

Comment: Don't use the stream readers, there so .Net 1, unless you have to. Use `File.ReadAllText` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things missing in the other answers:

- No validation is done to check if the text is a word
- Comparison should not be case-sensitive (i.e. `spain`, `Spain` and `SPAIN` should be considered the same word)

My solution:

```
StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
string text = "The 'rain' in spain falls mainly on the plain. 07 November 2018 20:02:07 - 20180520 I said the Plain in SPAIN. 12345";

var dictionary = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+")
                      .Where(IsValidWord)
                      .GroupBy(m => m, comparer)
                      .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Count(), comparer);
```

Method `IsValidWord`:

```
// logic to validate word goes here
private static bool IsValidWord(string text)
{
    double value;

    bool isNumeric = double.TryParse(text, out value);

    // add more validation rules here

    return !isNumeric;
}
```

### EDIT

I noticed in your code that you have a Dictionary with the [words grouped by first letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319577/558486). This can be achieved like this (using the previous dictionary):

```
var lettersDictionary = dictionary.Keys.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 1), 
        (alphabet, subList) => new {
            Alphabet = alphabet,
            SubList = subList.OrderBy(x => x, comparer).ToList()
        })
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Alphabet, m => m.SubList, comparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just split with a regex, then use LINQ to create your dictionary:

```
var dictionary = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+")
    .GroupBy(m => m, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) // Case-insensitive
    .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Count());
```

**UPDATE**

In applying to your example code, your task class could become something like this to build both dictionaries (and to consider case insensitive):

```
public class Aufgabe
{
    const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜ";
    public Dictionary<string, int> words;
    public Dictionary<char, List<string>> firstletter;
    public Aufgabe(string filename)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        words = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+")
            .GroupBy(m => m, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Count());
        firstletter = ALPHABET.ToDictionary(a => a, // First-letter key
            a => words.Keys.Where(m => a == char.ToUpper(m[0])).ToList()); // Words
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with Regex, note that case sensitivity has not been addressed

```
var text = "The 'rain' in spain falls mainly on the plain. I said the plain in spain";

var result = new Dictionary<string,string>();

Regex.Matches(text, @"[^\s]+")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\W", string.Empty))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(word =>
     {
        if (!result.ContainsKey(word))
            result.Add(word, word);
     });
```

result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a job for regular expressions. `\W+` splits your input string into words, defined as any character sequence of alphanumeric characters. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter).

```
string sentence = "You are pretty. State-of-the-art.";
string[] words = Regex.Split(sentence, @"\W+");

foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (word != "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```